# flutter firebase to python firebase

Tags: python, flutter, firebase, flask

is there a way that two firebase servers can communicate withone another?

I have a flutter-firebase app.

I also have a python-firebase app.

the goal is to make a http request from flutter app to the python server so that I can do some data processing in the python server.

the issue is that the files that are needed to do the data processing are on in firebase.

the success factor would that the python server receives a request, validates the request, retrieve the files from firebase, perform the analytics on it, then return the response.

here is my python code so far::

```
from flask import Flask, request
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth

cred = credentials.Certificate('ops-manager-eebe0-firebase-adminsdk-25jf3-5abab2aa28.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process_message', methods=['POST'])
def process_message():
    try:
        # Get user ID and message from the request
        user_id = request.form.get('user_id')
        message = request.form.get('message')

        # Authenticate the user
        try:
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(user_id)
            # User is authenticated
            print(f"User ID: {decoded_token['uid']}")
        except ValueError as e:
            # User authentication failed
            print(f"Authentication failed: {e}")

        # Process the message
        print(f"Message: {message}")

        return 'Message received'
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing message: {e}")
        return 'Error'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

here is the class in the flutter app that is making the http request::

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class ServerClient {
  static const String serverUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String?> getAccessToken() async {
    try {
      final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        final idTokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult(true);
        final accessToken = idTokenResult.token;
        return accessToken;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting access token: $e');
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> sendMessage(String message) async {
    try {
      final accessToken = await getAccessToken();
      print('accessToken: ${accessToken}');
      if (accessToken != null) {
        final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse('$serverUrl/process_message'),
          headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
          body: {
            'user_id': _auth.currentUser?.uid,
            'message': message,
          },
        );

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print('Message sent successfully');
        } else {
          print('Failed to send message');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending message: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

when i try to make an htttp request to the python server I see the following error::

```
Error processing message: Wrong number of segments in token: b'3MGJavn5UAeHtLfWCnxr1v2bGus2'
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2023 14:52:14] "POST /process_message HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

any ideas how to work around this issue?